# Javascript de-focus textfield input

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

I have a modal that I pop up with jQuery with a textfield on which I want to trigger the `focus()` event.
Problem is the fextfield IS allready focused.. In most browsers it is even highlighted. (I have no idea why?)

How can I de-focus or de-select the text so I can use the `focus()` event?

```
<input type="text" class="shortcut" id="input-shortcut" value="<?= $shortcut_url; ?>" />

$(".shortcut").focus(function() { 
    $(this).addClass("focus");
    $(this).select();
}).blur(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("focus"); 
});
```

Comment: It seems to be no problem to trigger the `focus` event if the input element already has focus: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/uT9d9/ (at least in Chrome and Firefox). Where are you trying to trigger it? You know that `$('.shortcut')` won't select your input element?

Comment: mmm it doesn't seem to work for .select() though?

Comment: Raising `select` works too: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/uT9d9/1/

Comment: Ok I just want one of them "copy the link" textfields, no Flash. When they click in the field (focus) select all the text. I also have the focus class for styling the field. I just don't get why the text is selected in my modal?

Comment: Just found a good solution for selecting the text, old skool JS: http://javascript-array.com/scripts/onclick_select_all_text_in_field/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $("#element").blur();

[jQuery documentation of blur](http://api.jquery.com/blur/)

Comment: actually your answer was all there :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery's blur() function. Which is basically like "out of focus"

Comment: yes but blur() is an event, how can I trigger it when the textfield is already focused?

Comment: @FFish: `element.blur()` but I'm pretty sure you don't need to "defocus" at all.